# String split issue based on pattern matching in java

Tags: java, string, split, pattern-matching

I want to split `GigabitEthernet0/1` to `GigabitEthernet` and `0/1`.
I tried using ,

```
str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```

But did not get correct result. What pattern should I use. The second part is not just digit, it also contains "/".

In my use case I may also have `GigabitEthernet0` which can be split to `GigabitEthernet` and `0`.

What could be the right regex?

Comment: Also be aware that if you're handling IOS configurations, you'll need to take into account subinterfaces: `Serial0/0.14`.

Answer (score 1):

try this regexp

```
([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9\/.:]+)
```

it works for

```
GigabitEthernet0/1 --> interface on chassis/card
GigabitEthernet0/1.1 --> interface with sub interface
Serial0/1/1:1.1 --> channelized serial/POS interface
GigabitEthernet0 --> interface on chassis (In some Cisco IOS devices)
```

Ex https://regex101.com/r/eP7kL3/1

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following regex to split

```
String gigaByteWithSlash = "GigabitEthernet0/1";
String gigaByteWithoutSlash = "GigabitEthernet0";
//String[] part = gigaByte.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d/\\d)");
String[] part00 = gigaByteWithSlash.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(part00[0]);
System.out.println(part00[1]);

String[] part01 = gigaByteWithoutSlash.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(part01[0]);
System.out.println(part01[1]);
```

Prints

```
GigabitEthernet
0/1
GigabitEthernet
0
```

Comment: Thank you. But this does not work when i have GigabitEthernet0. Tried String[] part = gigaByte.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)"); But this does not work for GigabitEthernet0/1

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] part = gigaByte.split("(?<=[\\w&&\\D])(?=\\d)");
```

works for both of my above mentioned cases.